# Link two faces to each other

Tags: faces

Im trying to "glue" the face of the steel block to the face of rubber cover. I want to create somthing like this with an accordion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNaiemTSa6s

What can I do to just glue the faces? Or do I need to rig everthing? I have search and search for a solution but could not find one. I'm using Blender 3.3

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wanna try a bendy bone? It works only in Blender and is similar to a Bezier curve. Like a bone with many segments and 2 other bones that work as handles. There are many tutorials at YT that show the setup.

Comment: Thank you, I will look it up!